# Initialisation of MTLArgumentEncoder

Tags: macos, gpu, metal

So, I am making a Metal Compute application. And according to good practices on Metal, `MTLComputePipelineState` should be initialised in the beginning of the program, because it is expensive. To make a `MTLComputePipelineState` I have to use an `MTLFunction` which is my kernel function. Something like this:

```
id<MTLFunction> myKernel = [_defaultLibrary newFunctionWithName:@"myKernel"];
_myPipelineState = [_device newComputePipelineStateWithFunction:myKernel error:&error];
```

In these kernels, I am using `MTLArgumentEncoders` to encode values into my Argument Buffer, which also uses Kernel function.
Something like this:

```
id<MTLArgumentEncoder> argInEncoder =
[myFunction newArgumentEncoderWithBufferIndex:ComputeBufferIn1];
```

Just a random question, since I'm caching my `MTLComputePipelineStates` should I also cache my `MTLArgumentEncoder`s, if they have any performance implications?

Thanks

Comment: Did you get answer to this question? I'm too looking for similar setup, where I have common shader / pipeline instance, but different materials that set different data into shaders to render different entities, I'm thinking if I should create multiple argument encoders per material (since they hold own MTLBuffers) or share the encoders by instead calling setArgumentBuffer multiple times when each materials tries to set the data.